# Elastic Beanstalk worker tier periodic task not running

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

I have a periodic task setup on an Elastic Beanstalk worker tier using the cron.yaml file.

I have two files in my app, in the root directory:

> cron.yaml
>
> index.php

The root path for my app is "/".

The cron.yaml looks like:

> `version: 1
>   cron:
>    - name: "emails"
>      url: "/"
>      schedule: "* * * * *"`

The index.php calls a request bin url with `file_get_contents`, to test if it's running.

The request bin never gets hit, so it looks like the cron script isn't running every minute like it should. I tried changing the url in cron.yaml to `/index.php` but still no dice.

Anybody know what might be wrong?

---

Edit: Here is the aws-sqsd/default.log:

`2015-05-15T12:49:43Z pollers: AWS::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
2015-05-15T12:49:43Z pollers: AWS::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
2015-05-15T12:49:43Z pollers: AWS::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
.......`

---

Edit 2: I added a queue to the worker (in the right region) and now here's the aws-sqsd/default.log:

`2015-05-15T18:53:32Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/]
2015-05-15T18:53:32Z http-err: b09629a7-c14e-469a-a980-a3ac2565e779 (17) 500 - 0.002
2015-05-15T18:53:34Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/]
2015-05-15T18:53:34Z http-err: b09629a7-c14e-469a-a980-a3ac2565e779 (18) 500 - 0.006
2015-05-15T18:53:36Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/]
2015-05-15T18:53:36Z http-err: b09629a7-c14e-469a-a980-a3ac2565e779 (19) 500 - 0.002
2015-05-15T18:53:38Z message: sent to %[http://localhost:80/]
2015-05-15T18:53:38Z http-err: b09629a7-c14e-469a-a980-a3ac2565e779 (20) 500 - 0.002`

Here's the /var/log/httpd/access_log too:

`127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2015:18:52:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2015:18:53:01 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2015:18:53:03 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.0"`

Comment: Can you take a snapshot of your logs? Specifically look under /var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log for worker tier daemon logs.

Comment: Sure, just edited my question and added them.

Comment: This is odd... Are you using a custom sqs queue? Can you check in the aws console if the queue exists? Also in case you are using your own queue is it in the same region?

Comment: I had no queue apparently. I made one now in the right region and assigned it to the worker. The logs show the worker trying to hit the URL now but getting a 500 (I edited my question above with the new logs).

Comment: So your application is throwing HTTP 500. Can you log something from your application? It depends on what your application is trying to do?

Comment: Can you please share your solution? Maybe I am having the same issue. I assume that i don't have to use the SQS since I just want to run a CRON task. It says "Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from cron.yam" but for any reason it does not execute it. I do not see any errors in the log files. The yaml file looks like: version: 1
cron:
 - name: "notify"          
   url: "/notify.php"      
   schedule: "* * * * *"

Comment: @TimJahn, do you remember what you did to make it work? I'm having the same issue, it's giving me a 500 HTTP error. Please, let me know. Thank you